# Xamarin Android NFC - starts a specific intent but I need to know if the app was previously killed, or not

Tags: android, xamarin, nfc

The app is a Xamarin Android app using NFC technology.

In the first place, the app start up, the user logs in, and then can tap NFC cards.   That's fine.

The problem is when the app is manually killed - remove from running tasks - then an NFC card is tapped and it triggers the app to open on the specific intent for that card, bypassing the login page.

I need to figure out how to know if the app was killed and is being opened by a card tapping.

The issue is that background services are started when the app is opened naturally, and this is bypassed if the app is killed/crashed and the user taps a card.

Any help in figuring out if the app was suddenly launched from an NFC card tapping, or if it was running normally and a card was tapped would be greatly appreciated.

I was thinking trying to count if there are any other pages in the stack, or in history, or some way of knowing if a service is busy running - the service was started using StartService

```
StartService (new Intent (this, typeof(DemoService)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Just save some value to preferences when app was started and remove it when app is shut down normally. If you app starts and value is in there you can see that app was killed.

Comment: Not sure if that works - if I add a value to preferences it will remember it when the app is killed and opened by an NFC card tapping.  For example I store the userid in preferences when the user logs in.  The app is shut down and when the card is tapped, the user still exists in preferences, and therefore the app thinks everything is okay.